# Error running docker compose up on Grid DB C Client while working on IOT project

Tags: docker, docker-compose, griddb

I have a docker-compose.yml file that include the images for Grid DB, Kafka, Zookeeper and Jupyter.

Griddb-server excerpt on docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  griddb:
services:
  griddb-server:
    build:
      context: griddb-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: griddb-server
    user: root
    expose:
      - '10001'
      - '10010'
      - '10020'
      - '10040'
      - '20001'
      - '41999'
    environment:
      NOTIFICATION_MEMBER: 1
      GRIDDB_CLUSTER_NAME: myCluster`
```

The Dockerfile running the gridb-server image

```
`from griddb/griddb

USER root

RUN set -eux \
    && apt-get update \
    # Install dependencies for griddb
    && apt-get install -y default-jre --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get clean all \
    # Delete the apt-get lists after installing something
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install GridDB c_client
WORKDIR /
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/griddb/c_client/releases/download/v5.0.0/griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb

RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/griddb/cli/releases/download/v5.0.0/griddb-ce-cli_5.0.0_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i griddb-ce-cli_5.0.0_amd64.deb


ADD start-griddb2.sh /
USER gsadm

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/start-griddb2.sh"]
CMD ["griddb"]`
```

I'm using M2 Mac OS. While running `docker compose up -d`, I ran into this error details:

> ERROR [iot_project-main-data-viz  3/12] RUN dpkg -i griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb                                                                    0.2s
> CANCELED [iot_project-main-jupyter 2/6] RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/griddb/c_client/releases/download/v5.0.0/griddb-c-client_5  0.0s
>
> [iot_project-main-data-viz  3/12] RUN dpkg -i griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb:
> #0 0.133 dpkg: error processing archive griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb (--install):
> #0 0.133  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
> #0 0.146 Errors were encountered while processing:
> #0 0.146  griddb-c-client_5.0.0_amd64.deb

I tried running `docker compose up` and expected to have my docker image built successfully. However, my docker compose up terminated with the above error which suggest that package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64) and the dpkg couldn't resolve the error.

Is there a solution to resolve the griddb-c-client on my docker-compose.yml file or do we have another url to download griddb-c-client for arm64 architecture?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It looks like there might be a different and significant error in the PNG rendering of the error from what you quote in plain text.  The plain-text error suggests an architecture mismatch with the downloaded file, which isn't necessarily a programming problem.

Comment: Thanks David, Actually, the error on plain-text was when running with docker compose up -d. I will remove the previous images. I'm sure this error occurred due to architecture problem and would like to know if someone else had a fix to this issue.